# Control order of script executions in test_package

Tags: r, devtools, testthat

Is it possible to control the order in which `test_package` executes testing scripts? I would like to start by executing some code that creates some objects shared by all individual tests. Therefore, this script needs to be executed first, before the actual `test-blabla.R` scripts.

I could try something like `test-AAA.R` or `test-000.R`, but I am not sure if the `dir` function used by `testthat` to list the scripts in a package, returns the same (alphabetical?) order of files on all platforms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`?test_dir` says

> Test files start with ‘test’ and are executed in alphabetical
>        order (but they shouldn't have dependencies). Helper files start
>        with ‘helper’ and loaded before any tests are run.

So, use helper files.  i.e. create a file with a name that begins with "helper" and put in it the code that you need to run before running all the tests.